# Bootstrap 4: Card header in accordion does not make text responsive for mobile size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

I do have an accordion in bootstrap 4. The text in the card header is not responsive so when it's length is more than the width of the card header, it displays outside.

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingEight">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEight" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEight">
                    <p>1. Header which is not responsive so in mobile it does not display right</p>
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseEight" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingEight" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body text-justify">
                Text here is responsive
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use a link (a href) instead of a button.

Answer (score 2):

Change class:

```css
.btn {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to:

```css
.btn {
    white-space: normal;
}
```